# Unzip files in folders automatically [mac os x]

Tags: terminal, unzip

I have a folder on my desktop that has around 2500 folders in it, each folder has multiple files in them that are zipped, I can unzip them by manually clicking on them, is there a way to do this automatically through terminal?

Comment: Can you highlight all of them and open them all at once (Command-o) to unzip them all?

Comment: I tried that but it crashes the Finder, there are way too many files.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`find ./ -name \*.zip -exec unzip {} \;` maybe?

Comment: that was perfect thank you! Except I had bz2 files, so I used `find ./ -name \*.bz2 -exec bunzip2 -k {} \;` instead!

Comment: Anyone can shed light or explain this syntax, please?

Comment: The proposed way extracts all the zips to the same folder. and if I want each unzipped file on the same subfolder as the parent zip?

Answer (score 11):

you can try the **unzip** command, but i think it only works with zip/tar files.

http://www.lifewithtech.net/apple/tip-unzip-multiple-files-into-a-single-directory-in-mac-osx/

http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/faq/extract

or if you have the app **The Unarchiver**:

you can use the **open** command.

**cd** to your folder and use:

```
$ open */*.rar
```

this should extract all rar files in all sub-folders, according to your Unarchiver setup into a new folder or in the same folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `open **/*gz` helped me; thanks :)